# I can't cast Exception to ValidationException in error handling middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pipeline, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I need some help in regards of **exception handling middleware** in **ASP.NET Core**.
I am using **Fluent Validation** to validate the input from user in a Pipeline with **MediatR**, the exception that gets thrown is `ValidationException`:

```
if (errors.Any())
{
    throw new ValidationException(errors);
}
```

It then gets caught by the mentioned middleware, but it is not `ValidationException` anymore. I can't cast to it. I want to retrieve errors from validation, but I can't because of that:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, e);
    }
}
```

If I change `Exception e` to `ValidationException e` it doesn't get caught at all.

And if I try this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ValidationException validationException = (ValidationException)e;
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, e);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.AggregateException' to type 'FluentValidation.ValidationException'.
   at Application.Middlewares.ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Programs\X\Application\Middleware\ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 24
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

This is my DependencyInjection.cs:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();
    services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    services.AddMediatR(c => c.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehaviour<,>));

    return services;
}
```

Everything is registered and Validation pipeline with the exception handler are working, it's just that I can't cast it to ValidationException.

Or this is not even how it should be done?

Comment: You should check: `e.InnerException`. `System.AggregateException` is the exception from tasks, the ÌnnerException should give the 'real' exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions thrown in tasks that aren’t awaited wrap exceptions in `AggregateException` and you can iterate through all the wrapped exceptions via the `InnerExceptions` property.  Your validation exception will be in there.